# PageAsyncTask Not Running in Parallel

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, pageasynctask

I am examining async web pages `async="True"`. In Page_Load, I am registering 3 tasks using RegisterAsyncTask. Each of these tasks is calling a SQL Server stored procedure. The stored procedure is doing a simple select and waiting for a couple of seconds using `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'`
My problem is that the pages takes 6 seconds to get back to me instead of just 2 seconds.

This is the trace of the page.

```
aspx.page   Begin Load           0.000173230943152662    0.000013 
Inside      BeginAsyncOperation1 0.000268187163843751    0.000095 
Inside      BeginAsyncOperation2 0.000517126445114984    0.000249 
Inside      BeginAsyncOperation3 0.000642237681836351    0.000125 
aspx.page   End Load             6.09175786420362        6.09111
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I've encountered this problem just now. Pro Asp.net 4 says the tasks run in parallel, but by reading source code of the page class, I found that the tasks are actually handled sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that you can use the "executeInParallel" parameter of the PageAsyncTask constructor to control this behaviour.

Comment: I am already using the last parameter as true `PageAsyncTask task1 = new PageAsyncTask(new BeginEventHandler(BeginAsyncOperation1), new EndEventHandler(EndAsyncOperation1), new EndEventHandler(TimeoutAsyncOperation1), null, true);` but they run sequentially.